# First request in website is slow hosted in Deluxe

Tags: asp.net, web-hosting, shared-hosting

I have a Deluxe Plan in Godaddy (Windows plan), where I host some websites. When I check my websites, the request spend more than 10 seconds, between sending request and receiving response. If I want to access to this site after several hours of inactivity, this happen again.

For this problem, I created a console application where, each 1 minute, it going to visit my websites. I hosted this application in Azure Web Job, but this wasn't a solution for my problem.

What I should do to my websites respond fast?, Regardless of user activity

Answer (score 0):

After deploying a website the first request takes longer, but after that it should load much quicker.

Comment: In this case, it doesn't happen. First request is longer, if I visit the website in short time, the page reply is fast. But I after several time of inactivity , I visit my website and the request take long time.

Comment: This could be with IIS. IIS will recycle worker threads if a site is not visited often. It sounds like this is the issue and not so much the website.

Comment: Try writing a small console app or scheduled task to just ping your site every so often and see if that helps.

Comment: Yes Brandon, thinking in it, I created a console application in c#. This app is currently run in Azure

Comment: The code app is the follow:

`static void Main(string[] args)
 {
            while (true){
                using (var client = new WebClient())
                {
                    var text = client.DownloadString("http://firstwebsite.com/");
                     text = client.DownloadString("http://secondwebsite.com/"); 
                    Thread.Sleep(60000);
                }
            }

}`